# How to force creation of a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, rm, ln

I have a particular directory full of other directories organized (named) by date.  For ease of reference, I have a symlink called `current` pointing to the latest one.

In the script that creates new date directories, I wish to create or fix the `current` symlink to point to the newest directory once created.

I thought the appropriate command would just be, e.g.,

```
ln -fs 2017-03-01 current
```

If the `current` symlink doesn't exist yet, this works.

---

However, if the `current` symlink has already been created (and points, let us say, at the directory `2017-02-28`), this **doesn't work:**

Instead of removing the symlink `current` and creating a new symlink `current` which points to `2017-03-01`, the result will instead be a broken symlink *called* `2017-03-01` pointing to **itself,** resting *inside* the directory `2017-02-28` (which is where the symlink `current` pointed and still points).

This baffled me, so [I read the specs for `ln`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html).  Turns out this is expected behavior:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> ln [-fs] [-L|-P] source_file target_file
>
> ln [-fs] [-L|-P] source_file... target_dir
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ...
>
> **The second synopsis form shall be assumed when the final operand names an existing directory.**

---

It seems, then, that there is no way whatsoever to *repoint a symlink* that currently points to a directory *to a new target,* where the new target has a name *different* from the name of the symlink.  So `ln -fs` doesn't work the way I thought it did.

*Must* I `rm current`, or is there another approach I've overlooked?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In GNU's `ln`, there is `ln -n`, which would allow re-pointing a symlink:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ ln -s dir1 sym
# dir1/
# dir2/
# sym -> dir1/

$ ln -nsf dir2 sym
# dir1/
# dir2/
# sym -> dir2/
```

BSD coreutils uses the flag `-h` the same way `-n` would be used, [but it is likely the binary may support `-n` just for compatibility with GNU](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ln&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=netbsd).

Repointing it to the same location also requires the `-f` flag.